# Problema com o reduce para calcular média aritmética de array

Tags: javascript, array

Dúvida com o método `reduce`. Não consigo realizar o cálculo da média aritmética, o resultado ate deu certo uma vez (4,375), entretanto, o código passa apenas a somar depois de uma primeira execução. Já consultei a documentação, mas mesmo assim não consigo resolver.

```
var valores = [1.5, 2, 4, 10];

var media = valores.reduce(function (total, item, indice, array) {  
  total = total + item;
    if(indice == array.lenght - 1) {
      return total / array.lenght;
    }
    
    return total;
});

console.log(media);
```

O código acima retorna `17.5`, sendo que deveria ser `4.375`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olhando o seu código, `length` está escrito errado (`lenght`). Corrigindo isto o código passa a funcionar:

```js
var valores = [1.5, 2, 4, 10];

var media = valores.reduce(function (total, item, indice, array) {
  total = total + item;

  if(indice == array.length - 1) {
      return total / array.length;
  }
    
  return total;
});

console.log(media);
```

Answer (score 6):

É até possível fazer tudo isso utilizando o `reduce`, mas não é o ideal, já que há a necessidade de se criar um código mais complicado do que o necessário.

A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/480781/69296) explica porque o código original não funcionou, mas o `reduce` não deveria ser usado para tudo (como muita gente pensa). Note que é muito mais "trivial" simplesmente usar o `reduce` para somar os elementos do que, além de somar, verificar se é o último elemento para enfim realizar a divisão.

Em suma, você não precisa utilizar o `reduce` para calcular a média. Se for utilizá-lo, deve ser apenas para reduzir todos os números da lista em um só (somando-os).

Uma vez que essa redução tenha sido feita, você pode calcular a média (dividindo o resultado da soma pelo comprimento do array original, isto é, o número de elementos).

Assim:

```js
function media(numeros) {
  const total = numeros.reduce((total, atual) => {
    return total + atual;
  });
  
  return total / numeros.length;
}

console.log(media([10, 20, 30, 40])); // 25
```

Veja que não é sequer necessário utilizar `reduce`. Algumas pessoas podem achar o seguinte mais simples:

```js
function media(numeros) {
  let total = 0;
  for (const numero of numeros) {
    total += numero;
  }
  
  return total / numeros.length;
}

console.log(media([10, 20, 30, 40])); // 25
```

Comment: Realmente não é o ideal, mas estou so estudando para sanar duvidas, e com ctz irei seguir as dicas deixadas, agradeço a paciencia e compreensão por explicar, show!!!!!