# Por que o retorno de reduce da NaN?

Tags: javascript

Comentei o return sum, propositalmente, por quê eu não entendi. Se eu retiro return sum, ele retorna a média certa, no entendo quando entra no if na última posição esse retorno mostra NaN. Mas por quê retorna NaN?

```
const mediaNumeros = numeros.reduce((sum, element, index, array) => {
    sum = sum + element;
    if (index == array.length - 1) {
        return Number((sum / array.length).toFixed(2));
    }
    // return sum;
}, 0)
```

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/480776/69296

Answer (score -4, accepted):

O return dentro do IF só vai funcionar no último elemento.
Todos os anteriores vão dar undefined.
Ficando undefined + o último valor = NAN.
E na última iteração ele vai entrar no if e retornar undefined + o sum.